# Translation inside a service best practice

Tags: symfony

I need to translate some text inside a service symfony2 application. I heard it's not a best practice to pass the container. Any simple examples? Thanks

Comment: Inject the translator

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it's a bad practice to pass the container as argument of your service, instead you should inject the translator like this :

```
my.service:
    class: My\AppBundle\MyService
    arguments: ["@translator"]
```